# Query mysql não funciona com váriavel - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

A query mysql funciona com variavel normal, mas não com variavel do post do jquery, exemplo:

**NÃO FUNCIONA**

```
$agenda=$_POST['agenda'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `compromiso` WHERE login LIKE 'alanps' AND agenda LIKE '$agenda' AND ano LIKE '$ano' AND mes LIKE '$mes' AND dia LIKE '$list_day'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**FUNCIONA**

```
$agenda="Agenda 1";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `compromiso` WHERE login LIKE 'alanps' AND agenda LIKE '$agenda' AND ano LIKE '$ano' AND mes LIKE '$mes' AND dia LIKE '$list_day'") or die(mysql_error());
```

jquery do post:

```
    $.post('calendario.php', {
            mes: mes,
            ano: ano,
            agenda: $("#agendanome").html()
        }, function(resposta) {
                $("#calendario").html(resposta);
        }, 'html');
```

se eu der um `print $agenda;` aparece "Agenda 1" dos dois jeitos!
tentei tambem `$agenda=html_entity_decode($agenda);` e não teve resultado!

Comment: Não funciona significa algum erro ou nenhum resultado é retornado?

Comment: Provavelmente o erro está em: `$("#agendanome").html()`, poste o HTML para ver o que você esta enviando na var agenda

Comment: se eu der um print $agenda; aparece "Agenda 1" dos dois jeitos!

Comment: tentei tambem $agenda=html_entity_decode($agenda); e não teve resultado!

Comment: Esse `$("#agendanome").html()` não esta enviando junto tags HTML ou espaços/linhas em branco? tente passar um `trim()` e um `strip_tags()`...

Comment: @Jader, funcionou com o trim(), valew!!!

Comment: use: `$("#agendanome").text()`, assim não passa o HTML junto

Comment: @Jader Já que você o ajudou, poste a sua resposta. Assim esta pergunta sai da sessão de não respondidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrupando as respostas que estão na seção de comentários, créditos @Jader e @papa-charlie:

`$("#agendanome").html()` pode estar enviando junto tags HTML ou espaços/linhas em branco. Para solucionar usar trim() e um strip_tags():

```
$agenda = strip_tags(trim($_POST['agenda']));
```

O envio pelo Jquery fica melhor se apenas com o conteúdo do campo, ao invés do HTML junto, usar `$("#agendanome").text()`.

```
$.post('calendario.php', {
            mes: mes,
            ano: ano,
            agenda: $("#agendanome").text() // esta linha foi alterada em relação ao código da pergunta
        }, function(resposta) {
                $("#calendario").html(resposta);
        }, 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
 $agenda=urldecode($_POST['agenda']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `compromiso` WHERE login LIKE 'alanps' AND agenda LIKE '$agenda' AND ano LIKE '$ano' AND mes LIKE '$mes' AND dia LIKE '$list_day'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**`urldecode`** É a função especifica para remover espaços de html de url.

**Jquery do post:**

```
$.post('calendario.php', {
        mes: mes,
        ano: ano,
        agenda: $("#agendanome").html()
    }, function(resposta) {
            $("#calendario").html(resposta);
    }, 'html');
```

**`strip_tags`** É função para remover HTML de strings, também pode ser usada.

Como não existe **`[espaço]`** em *URL*, ele insere **`%20`** no lugar de espaços.